# Multitple Navigation title text - swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar, titleview

I am trying to display names on a custom navigation title
For long names it is truncating, How do I display the text in multiple lines for long names, Here is the code I used for custom titleView

```
nameLabel.font = UIFont(name: “Arial-Medium", size: 19)
nameLabel.textAlignment = .center
nameLabel.numberOfLines = 2
nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
nameLabel.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
self.navigationItem.titleView = nameLabel
```

Comment: @TheTiger : A little wrong. adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth works with any non zero value.

Comment: I have not tried this recently.

Comment: @TheTiger : This behaviour was the same since this property was introduced. Can you please share what you exactly mean by **recently** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can really control this behaviour if the text is very very long. Depending on the font size, you might be able to show full text but that too if is not too long (does not exceeds height of navigation bar/label). However here are few things might want to change :

```
nameLabel.numberOfLines                =   2
nameLabel.lineBreakMode                =   NSLineBreakMode.ByTruncatingTail
nameLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth    =   true
nameLabel.minimumScaleFactor           =   0.4
```

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: I have. Have you ?

Comment: Thank your for the support. it is working fine

Comment: Great @VineeshTP !!

Comment: I am not arguing. I am just defending my answer.